# adding simple event listener

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, addeventlistener

I need to add a simple event listener. It just doesn't work even while testing with console.log. Here are my files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>CHAT</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input id='input' cols="30" rows="10"></input>
        <button id='send'>Send</button>
    </form>
    <div id='output' style='background-color: aqua;'> 1 </div>
</body>


<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.2/socket.io.js'></script>
<script src="./scripts/sockets.js"></script>
</script>

</html>
```

sockets.js

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/chat');
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var send = document.getElementById('send');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
console.log('send');
send.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('event listener added');
    /*socket.emit('sending', {
        input: input.value
    });
    input.value = '';*/
});
```

Also I want to admit that path is correct. "Send" was posted in console, but 'event listener added' - was not.

Comment: I found out that everything is working in case of changing <button> to <div>,  what this could mean?. In case of single click nothing is logged, in case of double click a have appropriate message but it erases from chrome console quickly.

Comment: Does your page reload when you press the send button? Because it is inside a form and could behave as a submit button.